# Dynamic Joptoinpane

Tags: java, dynamic, jtextfield, jcombobox, joptionpane

I have created a program that i would like to dynamically change when a user either selects `"Single", "Multiple"` inside of a drop down menu, Heres the code now.

```
public class Proxy {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception , IOException , FileNotFoundException {

    //Start of Dialog Box

    JComboBox<String> Server = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] { "us", "usrelease", "uk", "ukrelease" , "ca" , "au" , "de" , "fr" , "at" , "ru" , "cn" , "es" , "jp" , "nz" , "hk" });
    JTextField Amount = new JTextField();
    JTextField Server1 = new JTextField();
    JComboBox<String> random = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] { "Single", "Multiple"});
    JComboBox<String> type = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] { "Static", "Sticky"});
    Object[] message = {
            "Server Code", Server,
            "Standard or Random", random,
            "How Many Different Proxies", Amount,
            "How Many Servers are Avalible", Server1,
            "Type", type,
    };
```

I would like to Change the textboxs to change to this code when user selects `Single` or `Multiple` to this code.

```
public class Proxy {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception , IOException , FileNotFoundException {

    //Start of Dialog Box

    JComboBox<String> Server = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] { "us", "usrelease", "uk", "ukrelease" , "ca" , "au" , "de" , "fr" , "at" , "ru" , "cn" , "es" , "jp" , "nz" , "hk" });
    JTextField Amount = new JTextField();
    JTextField ServerNumber = new JTextField();
    JComboBox<String> random = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] { "Single", "Multiple"});
    JComboBox<String> type = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] { "Static", "Sticky"});
    Object[] message = {
            "Server Code", Server,
            "Standard or Random", random,
            "How Many Different Proxies", Amount,
            "What Server Number", ServerNumber,
            "Type", type,
    };
```

So from this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw7Xd.png]

to this After Change is Completed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2PyY.png]

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see is the label could be either:

1. How many servers are available
2. What server number

So instead of passing a String to the option pane, pass in a JLabel (ie. a realy component, like you do for the text fields and combo boxes).

Then you can add an `ActionListener` to your combo box. Whenever the listener fires you get the currently selected value from the combo box and then you change the text of the label to the appropriate value.

Comment: There’s also a change to the variable What server number is saved under. Could you explain in coding form?

Comment: @DevinRaynovich, Why do you think you need a change in the variable on the option pane? Once the dialog closes you get the selected value of the combo box and assign the number entered to the appropriate variable.